# How can I derive the equation for the angle of a simple pendulum as a function of time without calculus?

Tags: trigonometry, physics

I want to derive the equation $\theta=\theta_0 \sin{\left(\sqrt{\frac{g}{L}} t\right)}$ from **force diagrams** and **circular motion** without using calculus. I have managed to get pretty close but I can't figure out how to obtain $\theta_0$ in the equation. I have checked other questions such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3682884/how-do-i-solve-the-differential-equation-for-the-motion-of-pendulum) or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1926262/a-general-formula-for-simple-pendulum), but none of them provide a detailed development. I have managed to reach the formula for the period $T=2\pi\sqrt\frac{L}{g}$ with trigonometry only, does that get me any closer?

Comment: that expression is totally incorrect, angle in a pendular motion is an elliptical function in time, if I recall correctly.

Comment: as far as I know, a simple pendulum follows that expression when applying the small angle approximation; at least, that's what I've found [here](https://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/Demos/Pendulum/Pendulum.html) (there they use the cosine instead but it's the same principle)

Comment: yeah, by using approximations, but the only way to choose these approximations (rigorously) is using calculus

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "choosing" approximations? I've already "chosen" to use the small angle approximation because I am dealing with very small angles, right?

Comment: well, how small do you want your angles? Why will you approximate $\sin (x)$ for $x$ instead of approximating it by, let's say, $\frac 25 x$? These answers come from calculus

Comment: yeah, but that is not part of the problem, I'm taking the small angle approximation as a granted. assuming the approximation, and using no further calculus, how can I derive the expression from Newton's laws, trigonometry, etc.? or rather, using as much basic calculus as needed, but without differential equations.

Comment: Since Newton's law $F=mx''$ is already in the form of a differential equation, I'm not really sure what you're hoping for

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2257095/exact-period-of-simple-pendulum?rq=1) complete answer which doesn't approximate anything and you probably should consider wasting some time on this and on real calculus (actually this would save you a lot of time), there is a lot of material online.

Let's say you've got a pendulum inclined from a small angle $\theta _0$, so small that $\sin (\theta) \approx \theta \approx \tan (\theta)$ and $\cos (\theta_0) \approx 1 - \frac{\theta_0^2}2$.

it's tangential acceleration is given by:

$a = \frac{P_ \theta}{m} = \frac{mg \sin (\theta)}m = g \sin (\theta) \approx g \theta$

notice that the acceleration is proportional to the distance of equilibrium, just like in an harmonic movement equation:

$a = - \frac km x = -\omega x$

so the movement will be like an MHS an the general equation will be:

$a = -\frac g L x \iff \omega = \sqrt{\frac g L}$ (the negative sign is because it goes faster as $x$ gets smaller, $x$ is the length of the circular arc $L \theta$). There is pure calculus behind this.

Comment: this is very useful, thank you! however, it is the same point where I had arrived. my problem is, how do I turn that into an expression for the angle as a function of time?

I understand the calculus/DEs behind it, the reason why I want to solve it without differential equations is more complicated :)

Comment: with the MHS solution: $x= x_0 \cos (\phi_0 +\omega t) $, but $x = L \theta$, just need to get $\phi_0$ such that $x(t=0) = x_0$